# Laravel 5 syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is the code in my controller:

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }

}
```

My App.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name=description content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        @yield('footer')
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And index.blade.php

```
<?php

@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Articles</h1>
@stop
```

This is the error that I get:

```
FatalErrorException in 5f3efcdeb3d9812b22b5491d0cba9f22 line 3:
syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)
```

Please help.

---

**Solution listed below**. While the issue is silly, and easy to fix - it's hard to find a straight answer via Google Search. Hence keeping this question.

Comment: 5f3efcdeb3d9812b22b5491d0cba9f22 is your view, when you runs your app thea blade views will be convert to a sample php temp file wich contains your view in normal php language. The temp view are stored in: `storage/framework/views/` try to open the `5f3efcdeb3d9812b22b5491d0cba9f22` file and see what happend

Comment: I had `<? @extends('layouts/default') ?>` where I needed to just remove the `<? ?>`

Comment: @VaelVictus you would need to remove "<?". If there is "?>", remove that as well.

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `<?php ?>` Tags are not required in **.blade.php** files. Remove them and it works.

(The blade syntax need not be in php tags. You can however, include PHP code in  tags.)

Answer (score 2):

The `<?php ?>` tags are not required in your laravel blade file saved with extension **.blade.php** laravel templating engine automatically parse blade commands from these files.

But if you want to include php code in your blade file which is not part of blade engine commands then you will have to use `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but the issue was clearly missed.

In your index.blade.php file your missing the closing php tag "?>".

The blade sytanx @extends, @section etc... should be in your html on the outside of any php code block.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@extends`, it must be the first piece of code in your blade file.

A blank space or an empty new line before `@extends` will also throw an error.